# Fixed points and permutations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Let $\psi ,\varphi  \in {S_n}$ two permutations.
Let $M$ a matrix such that $a_{i,j}=1$ iff $i=\sigma(j)$ where $\sigma \in S_n$ ($0$, otherwise)

I already showed that $tr(M) = \left| {\left\{ {k \in \{ 1...n\} |k = \sigma (k)} \right\}} \right|$

Now, I've been told to consider the following identity: $tr(XY) = tr(YX)$ and to conclude that for $\psi ,\varphi \in S_n$: the number of fixed points of $\psi\varphi$ equals to the number of fixed points of $\varphi\psi$. I demanded to show it without directly using matrices.

Any idea how?

**A Thought:**
is that right to say that:
$$tr({M_{\psi \varphi }}) = tr({M_\psi } \cdot {M_\varphi }) = tr({M_\varphi } \cdot {M_\psi }) = tr({M_{\varphi \psi }})$$

Comment: That's fine, provided you understand why $M_{\psi\phi}=M_{\psi}M_{\phi}$.

Comment: Hmm.. Not completely actually.

Comment: Good. Now you know what you have to figure out.

Comment: Any progress on this, Annie?